# Handiling variables in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make an app where when a button is pressed, it loads a random screen.

```
const Slides = [Slide0, Slide1, Slide2, Slide3, Slide4, Slide5];

randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      randomNumber: 1,
    };
  }

  _onPressButton = () => {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    this.setState({randomNumber: randomNumber});
    this.props.navigation.navigate('NextScreen');
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        source={require('./assets/icons/app-icon.png')}
        style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
      />
        <Text style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>Welcome to Dementia Care Activities.</Text>
        <Text>Next slide should be: {this.state.randomNumber}</Text>
        <Text>{randomNumber}</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={this._onPressButton}
          title="Get New Activity"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const SimpleAppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  NextScreen: { screen: Slides[randomNumber] }
});

const AppNavigation = () => (
  <SimpleAppNavigator  />
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <AppNavigation/>
    );
  }
}
```

The issue here is that the value for `randomNumber` never gets updated again when the button is clicked, however the rest of the code in `_onPressButton` runs as expected.

When I reload the app, I get a different randomly assigned value for `randomNumber` but then that value cannot be overridden.

How do I make it so that the value is updated?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a variable inside your render function then you need to declare that in state. if you want this line

`<Text>{randomNumber}</Text>`

in your render to reflect new random number then you need to use

`<Text>{this.state.randomNumber}</Text>`

instead. Let me know if this isn't what you are looking for :)

Comment: That is not quite what I'm looking for.  The issue is that when the button is pressed and the function `_onPressButton` is run, the new value is not passed to `randomNumber` in

    const SimpleAppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    NextScreen: { screen: Slides[randomNumber] }
    });

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('NextScreen', randomNumber);
```